# Kubernetes - Windows 10 - connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I've installed Kubernetes on windows 10 pro. I ran into a problem where the UI wasn't accepting the access token I had generated for some reason.

So I went into docker and reset the cluster so I could start over:

[image]

But now when I try to apply my configuration again I get an error:

```
kubectl apply -f .\recommended.yaml
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:61634: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I have my `KUBECONFIG` variable set:

```
$env:KUBECONFIG
C:\Users\bluet\.kube\config
```

And I have let kubernetes know about the config with this command:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("KUBECONFIG", $HOME + "\.kube\config", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Yet, the issue remains! How can I resolve this?  Docker seems fine.

Answer (score 10):

This [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012973/kubernetes-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-127-0-0-18080) answered my question.

This is what it says:

> If you have kubectl already installed and pointing to some other environment, such as minikube or a GKE cluster, be sure to change
> context so that kubectl is pointing to docker-desktop:

```
kubectl config get-contexts

kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

Apparently I had installed `minikube` which is what messed it up. Switching back to a docker context is what saved the day.

Comment: Switching back to a docker context is what saved my day, too. 
Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

if you work on minikube in windows machine, try that:
`minikube start`